# How to change the shape of NEO4j nodes through the grass stylesheet?

Tags: neo4j, grass-file

I would like to provide better visual segregation between nodes in Neo4j's web explorer. Is it possible to change the grass styles to allow for a square-shaped node? Below is an example of the node style I would like to alter. Is this possible within Neo4j or must an outside visualization library be used?

```
node {
  diameter: 40px;
  color: #DFE1E3;
  border-color: #D4D6D7;
  border-width: 2px;
  text-color-internal: #000000;
  caption: '{id}';
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now it isn't possible, but it's on the todo list.

What you can do is to have wider borders and more distinct border colors to get a better distinction. You can also choose a color palette with more distinguishable colors for the backgrounds.

If you want to you can have a look a the previous http://localhost:7474/webadmin UI which had more styling options. Otherwise you'd have to go do something yourself where this can help: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/

Comment: Neo4j does not currently provide a way to edit/configure the node svg in D3.js? The more I think about it I am looking for greater customization of node clustering. If squares are on the todo list that is great in my book.Thanks.

Comment: @Micheal Hunger, it has been almost two years ago. Is it possible to change the shape of circles in a graph now?

Comment: It's 4 years now.

Comment: @Michael Hunger    please help me with below query  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72492947/how-to-access-json-values-of-neo4j-graph-from-grass-file